# Curl Post request raise error (422) due to model validation despite the request seems to be correctly set

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, curl

I am trying to create a simple crud interface that spits out some json. (api)

I'm using the inspiring spree code base in order to make it, by now, there is no token to make it secure

Please see the code below:

#### helper/api/api_helper.rb

```
module Api
  module ApiHelper
    def required_fields_for(model)
      required_fields = model._validators.select do |field, validations|
        validations.any? { |v| v.is_a?(ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator) }
      end.map(&:first)
    end

    def product_attributes
      [:id, :name]
    end
  end
end
```

#### views/api/products/new.rabl

```
object false
node(:attributes) { [*product_attributes] }
node(:required_attributes) { required_fields_for(Product) }
```

#### controllers/api/products_controller.rb

```
def new
end

def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])
  if @product.save
    respond_with(@product, :status => 201, :default_template => :show)
  else
    invalid_resource!(@product)
  end
end
```

When I do a post request via curl the method returns a 422 Unprocessable Entity error due to the fact that the product name should not be empty (model validation). As you could see the name is correctly set!!

Didn't find what's wrong with this (serialization?) thank you for your thought

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"attributes":{"name":"test"}}'  http://localhost/api/brands

* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/products HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.7 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost
> Accept: application/json
> Content-type: application/json
> Content-Length: 31
> 
< HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< X-Meta-Request-Version: 0.2.0
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: e32527947ed4ae51052b4d65d9d4539f
< X-Runtime: 0.042655
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
{"errors":{"name":["doit \u00eatre rempli(e)"]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON payload is expected to be nested under the model's name. Try this:

```
-d ' {"product":{"name":"test"}}'
```

Comment: Hi, in fact I've tried this, it's raising a not available message error. Using Rabl, I think my starting node is "attributes" as I set it in the template. I've also tried: '{"attributes":{"product":{"name":"test"}}}' but it doesn't work too..

Comment: I don't see how your Rabl template could affect the create action.

Comment: You're completly right, I have some constraints in my model which unvalidate the request